# Java Initializing a subclass

Tags: java, instantiation, subclass

What is the appropriate way to initialize an implemented class of an interface (determined by some logic)

Example

```
IAnaimal is an interface
Cat -> IAnimal
Dog -> IAnimal
Cow -> IAnimal


int x = in.nextInt();
IAnimal animal = null;

if(x==1)
 animal = new Dog();
else if(x==2)
 animal = new Cat();
else
 animal = new Cow();

animal.destroyManKind();
```

Is this the correct approach? Is there a 'more' professional way of doing this?

Comment: where does the `in.next()` came from? You might use a `switch instead of `if-else of -else`

Comment: It's a lot simpler than you're making it out to be: 1) An "interface" is implemented by a concrete class.  2) the concrete class is initialized by its constructor.  As easy as that! :)

Comment: You can simply use the reference and object of the same `class` or direct-type. `Dog d = new Dog();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have a cleaner way of reading the name instead of 1, 2 and 3 but you can use a switch in this case.

```
int choice = in.nextInt();

switch(choice) {
  case 1: animal = new Dog(); break;
  case 2: animal = new Cat(); break;
  default: animal = new Cow(); break;
}
```

or using a string switch

```
String choice = in.next();

switch(choice.toLowerCase()) {
  case "dog": animal = new Dog(); break;
  case "cat": animal = new Cat(); break;
  case "cow": animal = new Cow(); break;
  default: // error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in your way of doing. You can also look in to [Factory design pattern](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they have a common super class Animal, it could have a static builder method that takes an int, you could do this

```
IAnimal animal = Animal.build(x);
```

where

```
public class Animal{
public static IAnimal build(int x){

 if(x==1) return new Dog();
 else if(x==2) return new Cat();

 return new Cow();
}}
```

Comment: Is that a design pattern reference? I mean, I agree. I would like to do something like this. What would that build method look like? I'm assuming this would turn IAnaimal into an abstract class then?

Answer (score 1):

```
    switch (x){
      case 1: 
       animal = new Dog();
       break;
      case 2:
       animal = new Cat();
       break;
      default
       animal = new Cow();
    }
```

Are you sure that `Cow` is a useful default?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a animal array

```
IAnimal animal = null;

IAnimal [] animals ={null,new Dog(),new Cat(),new Cow()};

animal = animals[x]
```

Comment: I don't like that approach. You are instantiating 3 objects, when you only need one.